# Command \nobreakspace unavailable when switching to T1 encoding under XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, font-encodings

I'd like to use the `luximono` face for monospaced typesetting under `XeLaTeX`. Since it is already installed in the MikTeX distribution under `T1 encoding`, I switch to the latter when I need monospaced type. In order to do this, I have defined corresponding commands, as shown in the MWE below. Now, if I do not redefine the control sequence `\nobreakspace` in a form such as, e.g., I have done for my MWE, I get the error message `Command \nobreakspace unavailable in encoding T1`. My redefiniton is a workaround to this problem, and it has to it more of a patch than of a satisfactory solution. Could anyone possibly explain what is going on and how to solve it in a more appropriate way?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}

\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers=OldStyle,Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont[BoldFont=texgyrepagella-bold.otf,
             ItalicFont=texgyrepagella-italic.otf,
             BoldItalicFont=texgyrepagella-bolditalic.otf]{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}

\usepackage{microtype}

\newcommand{\xlxmono}{
            \def\nobreakspace{\nobreak\space\nobreak}
            \fontfamily{ul9}\fontencoding{T1}
            \selectfont
           }
\renewcommand*{\ttfamily}{\xlxmono}
\renewcommand*{\texttt}[1]{
            {\xlxmono #1}
           }

\begin{document}

    {\ttfamily This is one line set in a monotype face with a nobreakspace command~here.}

    \texttt{This makes for yet another line with~it.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should not be using `fontenc` with `fontspec`: the latter uses special 'Unicode encodings' as the way things work with XeTeX and LuaTeX is very different from 'traditional' LaTeX encodings.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: I do agree, but in this case it is not a troublemaker. I would delete it ftom my MWE, but since it is mentioned in other contributed comments and answers, I think it's better to keep it.

Comment: @JosephWright It seems to be sometimes necessary: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115627/18401.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé The encoding is wrong: hyphenation for slots 128-255 will be incorrect if you do this. You _really can't_ use traditional TeX fonts reliably with XeTeX/LuaTeX, at least without a lot of effort.

Comment: @JosephWright Hence no hope to use `kpfonts` with `fontspec`?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Unless all of your text is in English, I'm afraid so. The LaTeX team have been 'worrying' about this area recently and although one can imagine approaches (loading multiple hyphenation patterns) they are complex and probably not generally useful.

Comment: @JosephWright For texts in French, I notice lots of differences with XeLaTeX, much less with LuaLaTeX (the remaining ones are probably due to `microtype` which behaves differently with PDFLaTeX and with LuaLaTeX).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you modify your example to

```
\show\nobreakspace
\usepackage{fontspec}
\show\nobreakspace
```

You will see

```
> \nobreakspace=macro:
->\protect \nobreakspace  .
l.9 \show\nobreakspace
```

...

```
> \nobreakspace=macro:
->\EU1-cmd \nobreakspace \EU1\nobreakspace .
l.11 \show\nobreakspace
```

which means that the EU1 encoding setup has changed `\nobreakspace` from being an encoding-independent command to an encoding-dependent command, but without setting up a default definition so it works in all encodings. Re-instating the original definition as the default  is probably the simplest thing, however note you should not be mixing `fontenc` and `fontspec` encoding definitions in a single document.

The original definition is

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\nobreakspace}{%
   \leavevmode\nobreak\ }
```

So you could declare a default via

```
 \DeclareTextCommandDefault{\nobreakspace}{\leavevmode\nobreak\ }
```

as noted in the comments.

Note that your definition would not work if it was used in vertical mode, eg the start of a paragraph as in that position the `\nobreak` would prevent a page break not a line break.

Unrelated to the question you have *lots* of white space tokens in your definition which will produce white space in the output: put a `%` at the end of every line within the definitiosn that ends with `}` or `{`.

Note also you need to use xelatex to use fontspec but you also load microtype which generates a warning that it does not work with xelatex:

```
Package microtype Warning: You don't seem to be using pdftex.
(microtype)                `microtype' only works with pdftex.
(microtype)                Try running `pdflatex' instead of `xelatex'.
```

Unless you have the beta version as pointed out by @UlrikeFischer. See.
http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/cgi-bin/package.cgi/action=view/id=423

Comment: `fontspec` can change things to be encoding-dependent as input encodings for UTF-8 input are not really the same thing as for 'traditional' LaTeX.

Comment: Yes didn't notice (or it didn't sink in)  that fontspec and fontenc were both loaded until I saw your comment on the question.

Comment: Its `xunicode` which changes `\nobreakspace`: It maps the command to `U+00A0`. I would use either `\DeclareTextCommand{\nobreakspace}{T1}{\leavevmode\nobreak\ }` or 
`\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\nobreakspace}{\leavevmode\nobreak\ }` which would not destroy the `xunicode` declaration for EU1. Regarding `microtype`: There exist beta versions which works with `xelatex`: http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/cgi-bin/package.cgi/action=view/id=423

Comment: @ David Carlisle: Thanks so much for such a detailed answer. Only a couple of comments: Ulrike Fischer is right in everything she says (in her comment on this post ;-)); in particular, on Microtype (beta) v2.5, which I am using. I think the white spaces in my commands do not really add any typeset spaces, although it's true one must be very careful about it when it comes to TeX, and my MWE is not a benchmark of LaTeX code editing. Finally, if I try my MWE with your answer, it works fine, but if I do in my original project, I end up with an error message.

Comment: @David Carlisle: (Continues from last comment) That project is a long class which loads many packages. The error I get is `File ended while scanning use of @LN`. I do not get any error message if I use my original tentative workaround -- as in my MWE. Any possible hints on this? I'm afraid I don't think that I can provide an MWE for this.

Comment: The lines _will_ cause extra space if you switch font mid-paragraph with those definitions. At the start of a par as in the MWE you would be OK. ` of @LN` means somewhere where escape char is 0 (no backslash) which usually means in font loading somewhere but I don't recognise a macro `(\)@LN` but I don't know fontspec too well.

Comment: @David Carlisle: Yes, you're right. About my `@LN` problem, it had to do with my misuse of the `caption` package as described in `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67005/problem-with-package-caption-and-command-captionsetup/67010#67010`.

Answer (score 5):

I'd simply provide a suitable definition for `\nobreakspace` in the T1 encoding and define `\ttfamily` so that it chooses both LuxiMono and the T1 encoding:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{ul9}
\xpatchcmd{\ttfamily}{\selectfont}{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont}{}{}
\DeclareTextCommand{\nobreakspace}{T1}{\leavevmode\nobreak\ }
```

Since `\texttt` relies on `\ttfamily`, it's not necessary to act on it.

Comment: Thanks for drawing my attention to the package `xpatch`. Yours is an interesting solution, and would consider it as another valid answer, but I'm afraid I can only select one.

Answer (score 3):

use this preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{microtype}

\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers=OldStyle,Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont[BoldFont=texgyrepagella-bold.otf,
             ItalicFont=texgyrepagella-italic.otf,
             BoldItalicFont=texgyrepagella-bolditalic.otf]{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}

\newcommand\xlxmono{%
            \def\nobreakspace{\nobreak\space\nobreak}
            \fontfamily{ul9}\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont}
\renewcommand*\ttfamily{\xlxmono}
\renewcommand*\texttt[1]{{\xlxmono #1}}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd rather not switch to  unicode-math for this project in particular -- actually, I'm stil more comfortable with the "regular" TeX math packages than with the Unicode-based -- mostly for the small number of alternatives the latter convey at the current stage of development.