# Problem with command \captionsetup from package caption

Tags: captions, memoir, naming

The following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{
         listformat=empty,
         tablename=Table,
         justification=justified,
         labelsep=quad,
         position=above,
         skip=\onelineskip,
         width=\linewidth,
         labelfont={small},
         font={small}
         }

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \caption{A table.}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

generates the error message `! Package caption Error: Can be used only in preamble`. If I comment the `\captionsetup` command, there is no such error message. I know the class `memoir` provides its own tools for captions, but I'd rather use the package `caption` for them. Anyone could possibly shed some light on this issue?

EDIT: As soon as I comment the key `tablename`, the problem disappears. But even though it works, I wouldn't call it precisely a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Edit:** Thanks to Gonzalo Medina, I think I have an explanation. `:)`

`tablename` and `figurename` are indeed valid entries for `\captionsetup`, as long as you are using it without the optional argument. The idea: `\captionsetup` without the optional argument works globally, so it makes sense to set both `figure` and `table` names via `figurename` and `tablename` respectivelly.

The following code works:

```
\captionsetup{
   tablename=Table,
   listformat=empty,
   justification=justified,
   labelsep=quad,
   position=above,
   skip=\onelineskip,
   width=\linewidth,
   labelfont={small},
   font={small}
}
```

We are setting the caption layout globally.

Now, when we provide the optional argument, we are limiting our scope to the float we are setting up. Say, if we use `\captionsetup[table]{...}`, we are configuring the captions within the `table` scope, so there's no point of using `tablename`, but only `name`.

We can use the `name` key instead of `tablename`, since we are configuring `table`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{
   name=Table,
   listformat=empty,
   justification=justified,
   labelsep=quad,
   position=above,
   skip=\onelineskip,
   width=\linewidth,
   labelfont={small},
   font={small}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

If we want to use `tablename` instead, we must use `\captionsetup` without the optional argument:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{
   tablename=Table,
   listformat=empty,
   justification=justified,
   labelsep=quad,
   position=above,
   skip=\onelineskip,
   width=\linewidth,
   labelfont={small},
   font={small}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Just for reference, another way to rename the table name is with `\renewcommand{\tablename}{Table}`. However, as AstroPig mentioned in the comments, it doesn't work if we use `babel` with the `french` language.

Comment: Interestingly, the `tablename` option is apparently used for French tables (ref. lines 66, 67, and 1043 in caption.sty). I wonder what would happen if the default language was set to French through babel.

Comment: Actually, I have used `tablename` and `figurename` as keys for that command in several classes of my own loading all of them the class `memoir`without that problem appearing, and typing the float name as set in the corresponding key. I don't really know what the problem is.

Comment: @AstroPig7: you are absolutely right, redefining `\tablename` as it is doesn't work with `babel` and `french`. Thankfully, I found that the `caption` package provides a `name` key exactly for this purpose - and it works with French too. `:)`

Comment: @Marcos: I really can't tell what happened. The `tablename` key is not part of the `caption` package specification. However, it provides a generic `name` key which can be used for renaming your float. I updated the answer accordingly, please make sure to use the `name` key instead of my first suggestion. `:)`

Comment: @Marcos: Thanks to Gonzalo Medina, we found the explanation for `tablename` vs. `name`. See my new edit. `:)`

Comment: Thanks so much. I had noticed that it worked fine if it was set as a collection of global values for every type of float, but didn't figure out what the problem coul possibly be when trying to set different values according to the type of float. I really appreciate your involvement. Of course, my appreciation to Gonzalo Medina, too.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the options for the caption package conflict with the definition of the memoir document class. The following Google Groups post should help.

Ref. 1: [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.text.tex/RzpI2ATMev0%5b1-25%5d).

Comment: I have checked your link, which led me to consider commenting some of the keys in the command. See my EDIT, please.

Comment: Please provide a complete answer. You can use the link as a reference.