# Command \nobreakspace unavailable in encoding EU1 if i use xelatex

Tags: xetex, font-encodings

This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifXeTeX
  \usepackage{xunicode} %Если не ошибаюсь, то этот пакет уже загружает fontspec
  \usepackage{xltxtra}  %особой роли не должен вроде как играть и в будущем скорее всего не будет нужен
  \usepackage{polyglossia}

  \setdefaultlanguage{polish}
  \setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[MeX,T1, plmath]{polski}
  \usepackage{datetime}
\fi
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[super]{cite}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{siunitx}    %Для использоваия едениц измерений СИ, пример смотреть в тексте
\sisetup{
output-decimal-marker = {,},    %sisetup нужен, что бы вместо точки можно было использовать запятую.
per-mode = symbol   %Это что бы \per давала косую черту
}   %Для перечисления настроек обязательно нужна запятая между ними

% \DeclareTextCommandDefault{\nobreakspace}{\leavevmode\nobreak\ }
```

With this preamble i get

> Command \nobreakspace unavailable in encoding EU1

If i uncomment \DeclareTextCommandDefault{\nobreakspace}{\leavevmode\nobreak\ } i get

> Undefined control sequence

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't load `xunicode` before `fontspec` (loaded by `xltxtra`). In a current system you don't need to load `xunicode` at all, `fontspec` will do it at the correct place.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, xunicode *must* be loaded to get dots underneath certain letters in a consistent manner, unless one resorts to [another solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20791/19544) for these dots. If fontspec is loaded before xunicode, or xlxtra, the dots do not work properly either. 
But if xunicode is called first, you get the error reported above, "Command \nobreakspace unavailable in encoding EU1 if i use xelatex".

Instead, I used the solution [suggested here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66951/19544) to redefine the \nobreakspace while using xunicode.