# How to Install mathdesign on TeXlive -- mktexpk and updmap errors

Tags: xetex, mathdesign

I'm trying to install the [mathdesign package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathdesign) on TeXlive, and running into a slew of issues involving `maketexpk` and `updmap` failures. Are there any step-by-step instructions to accomplish this?

Here's what I've done so far:

First, I was trying to use `\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}`, but ran into this problem during a `xelatex` compile with LaTeX headers:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,fleqn}
\usepackage{theorem}% Bold Math package

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}

\usepackage[EU1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bm}% Bold Math package -- install AFTER \usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}

% bold math and math italic macros

\def\alphab{{\protect\bm{\alpha}}}
\def\Gammab{{\protect\bm{\Gamma}}}
\def\Ab{{\protect\mathbf{A}}}
\def\zerob{{\protect\bm{0}}}
\def\oneb{{\protect\bm{1}}}
\def\Rbmit{{\protect\bm{R}}}
\def\Xbmit{{\protect\bm{X}}}
\def\Ybmit{{\protect\bm{Y}}}
\def\Zbmit{{\protect\bm{Z}}}
\def\Rbbb{{\mathbb{R}}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66949/command-nobreakspace-unavailable-when-switching-to-t1-encoding-under-xelatex
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\nobreakspace}{\leavevmode\nobreak\ } 

\begin{document}

A pretty fact for a square matrix~$\Ab$
and~${t\in\Rbbb}$: \begin{equation} \det e^{\Ab t} =
  e^{t\tr\Ab}.\end{equation} The Riemannian curvature tensor using bold
math italics: \begin{equation} \Rbmit(\Xbmit,\Ybmit)\Zbmit
  =\bigl([\nabla_\Xbmit,\nabla_\Ybmit]-\nabla_{[\Xbmit,\Ybmit]}\bigr)\Zbmit.\end{equation}
The generalized gamma function $\Gammab_\alphab(\Ab)=\zerob$.

\end{document}
```

Error:

```
...
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/mdugm/m/sl' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/mdugm/m/n' instead on input line 42.

[1] (./foo.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.


kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 md-gmr8y
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for md-gmr8y.
mktexpk: perhaps md-gmr8y is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

** WARNING ** Could not locate a virtual/physical font for TFM "md-gmr8y".
** WARNING ** >> There are no valid font mapping entry for this font.
** WARNING ** >> Font file name "md-gmr8y" was assumed but failed to locate that font.
** ERROR ** Cannot proceed without .vf or "physical" font for PDF output...

Output file removed.
 )
Error 256 (driver return code) generating output;
file foo.pdf may not be valid.
Transcript written on foo.log.
```

So I tried to install `mathdesign` (which has `md-gmr8y`) into `texmf-local` by doing the following.

```
cd ~/Downloads/mathdesign
sudo mkdir /opt/local/share/texmf-local/tex/latex/mathdesign
sudo rsync -va ./latex/ /opt/local/share/texmf-local/tex/latex/mathdesign

sudo rsync -va ./afm/ /opt/local/share/texmf-local/fonts/afm

sudo rsync -va ./opentype/ /opt/local/share/texmf-local/fonts/opentype
sudo rsync -va ./tfm/ /opt/local/share/texmf-local/fonts/tfm
sudo rsync -va ./type1/ /opt/local/share/texmf-local/fonts/type1
sudo rsync -va ./vf/ /opt/local/share/texmf-local/fonts/vf

sudo mkdir -p /opt/local/share/texmf-local/fonts/map/pdftex/mathdesign
sudo rsync -va ./map/ /opt/local/share/texmf-local/fonts/map/pdftex/mathdesign

sudo mkdir -p /opt/local/share/texmf-local/fonts/enc/mathdesign
sudo rsync -va ./enc/ /opt/local/share/texmf-local/fonts/enc/mathdesign

sudo mkdir -p /opt/local/share/texmf-local/dvipdfm/config
sudo rsync -va ./config/ /opt/local/share/texmf-local/dvipdfm/config

sudo vi /opt/local/var/db/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
```

> ```
> # mathdesign
> Map mdput.map
> Map mdugm.map
> Map mdbch.map
> Map mdpus.map
> Map mdpga.map
> Map mdici.map
> ```

```
sudo mktexlsr
sudo updmap
```

But this results in the `updmap` error:

```
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /var/root/.texlive2012/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /opt/local/var/db/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
dvips output dir: "/var/root/.texlive2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
pdftex output dir: "/var/root/.texlive2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
dvipdfmx output dir: "/var/root/.texlive2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"
pxdvi output dir: "/var/root/.texlive2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pxdvi/updmap"

ERROR:  The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
    mdpga.map (in /opt/local/var/db/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)

    Did you run mktexlsr?

    You can disable non-existent map entries using the option
      --syncwithtrees.
```

I know I put the file `mdpga.map` in `/opt/local/share/texmf-local/fonts/map/pdftex` because I can see it there and the results of `mktexlsr`. Is that where it should go? I'm at a loss for the limited mathdesign installation and `updmap` documentation.

Comment: You want to load an Open Type Font (you use `\setmainfont`) but you are not loading `fontspec`. Only then you can set an OT font! Fontspec also does not require any updmapping. So include `\usepackage{fontspec}` before `\setmainfont`. An alternative to `mathdesign` which requires the proper installation of URW Garamond (not the same as Adobe Garamond!) is the `mathastext` package. This sets the letters and numbers of the math font to your main text font.

Comment: Thanks, Jörg. That's correct, but not my actual issue. I've edited my post to code that tickles the bug. I'm trying to install a package that will typeset Adobe Garamond with bold math included in the same style. Any idea why updmap fails?

Comment: Just a hint, if you want to address someone in a comment use "@username", then we get a notification.

Comment: Regarding your issue, do you need the `mdpga` at all? I think that's for Pagella (Palatino). Anyway, is the `map` file suppposed to go into the `pdftex` folder? On my TeXLive they are in `texmf-local\fonts\map\dvips\<fontname>`. I still think your objective can be achieved with `mathastext`. Have you tried that?