# How do I use kpfonts with fontspec?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, kpfonts

Is there a way to use `kpfonts` with `fontspec` ?

The math font is correctly used but just loading the `kpfonts` package is not enough for the text. If I add the `\setmainfont` line (see example) the kp font is used everywhere but bold text is not bold. If I add the `\fontencoding` line (see example) it is used correctly in the text (including bold) but not for the section titles (either regular kp font or bold computer modern font whether the other line is present or not). I don't really know what this line does (saw it somewhere on the internet).

Here is my minimal (non)working example:

```
\documentclass[article,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[ExternalLocation]{jkpmn8a.pfb}

\begin{document}
\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{jkp}\selectfont

\section{section}
\section{other section}
\subsection{my subsection}

bla bla bla. \textbf{bold}
$v_t : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: Short answer: Not at all! Should be clear after Herbert's answer. Either Kp-Fonts or other Type1 fonts with `fontenc` or TrueType/OpenType fonts with `fontspec`.

Comment: Addition: Generally, Truetype fonts could be used with `fontenc`, but this would need a map file – and this is missing for almost all fonts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

with XeLaTeX use:

```
\documentclass[article,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\begin{document}    
\section{section}
\section{other section}
\subsection{my subsection}

bla bla bla. \textbf{bold}
$v_t : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $

\fontspec{Garamond Premier Pro}
foo bar öäöä

\end{document}
```

then you'll get the embedded KP fonts:

```
herbert@shania:~/Dokumente> pdffonts test.pdf
name                          type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
----------------------------- ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
TKCZXS+Kp-Medium              Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no       4  0
DRXZLW+Kp-Regular             Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no       5  0
YKPDIX+Kp--M-Italic           Type 1C           Builtin          yes yes no       6  0
YASURJ+Kp--M-Syb-Regular      Type 1C           Builtin          yes yes no       7  0
DVMGXE+Kp--M-Sy-Regular       Type 1C           Builtin          yes yes no       8  0
QMYVMX+GaramondPremrPro-Identity-H   CID Type 0C Identity-H  yes yes yes 10  0
```

Comment: Well, it works, but then I can't use `fontspec` at all...

Comment: why do you need `fontspec` when you want to use Type 1 fonts??

Comment: I need to use other fonts in some places

Comment: Then use an OpenType font for all which makes more sense. Pagella, for example, is similiar to kpfonts and has math, too

Comment: I know I can do that and I'll probably end up doing this if nobody has an answer, but I like `kpfonts` and if there is a solution I would like to know it.

Comment: see my edited answer

Comment: Thank you !! I could have sworn I had tried that but I guess I was loading fontenc before fontspec and it didn't work.