# XeLaTex: 'Font Shape undefined'

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I'm trying to use custom fonts, but I can't get it to work. Compiling with XeLaTex

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{primary}{HTML}{2b2b2b}

\setmainfont[Color=primary, 
Path = fonts/lato/,
BoldItalicFont=Lato-RegIta,
BoldFont=Lato-Reg,
ItalicFont=Lato-LigIta]{Lato-Lig}

\begin{document}

Test example

\end{document}
```

Build Log Output:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/Lato-Lig(0)/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 13.
```

Folder Structure (ls -R)

```
fonts  test.tex   
./fonts: lato
./fonts/lato: Lato-BlaIta.ttf  Lato-Bol.ttf     Lato-LigIta.ttf  Lato-Reg.ttf Lato-Bla.ttf     Lato-HaiIta.ttf  Lato-Lig.ttf Lato-BolIta.ttf  Lato-Hai.ttf     Lato-RegIta.ttf
```

Comment: don't use `fontenc` with `xetex` just use `fontspec`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It seems to be sometimes necessary: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115627/18401.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé well maybe I should have said don't use legacy 8bit text fonts with xetex. (hyphenation will be wrong if you set text in T1 encoding, for a start)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Same arguments as Joseph's ones, [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66949/18401) :)

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to load `Lato-Lig.ttf` with the T1 encoding, rather than TU? If not, remove `\usepackage{T1}[fontenc]`.

Comment: Another thing to check is whether you're using so called **variable fonts**. Such files store multiple fonts at once, so `XeLaTeX` cannot pick out bold, italic etc. from the file name. There might be a way to specify it explicitly, but I don't know how. This happened to me: I used `Raleway` as a collection of `.ttf`s on one computer and a variable-font file on another, and it wouldn't compile bold/italic on the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Deedy Resume issue(s) as addressed in 2018 4Q. There may be some changes during the past 4 yrs to one or more of the relevant packages. To address related questions, I've had to edit the .cls file for (a) font access and (b) compiling, generally [*e,g.,* there are two `\\}` that should be `\\ }` in the openfont .cls file].

Regarding font specific matters, using the openfont .cls file as an example, editing the .cls file by

- (A) removing all `Path =` segments, and
- (B) using the specific fontfilename, e.g., `{Lato-Lig.ttf}`, `{Lato-Bol.ttf}`, `{Raleway-ExtraLight.otf}`, and `{Raleway-Medium.otf}`  with similar specifics in the fontface assignments, e.g., `BoldItalicFont=Lato-RegIta.ttf`,

then

- (C) manually adding the font into the known texlive structure (if not already there) [it's good to put `.ttf` files in the `truetype` folder and `.otf` files in the `opentype` folder [followed, of course by `mktexlsr` and `fc-cache -fv` from the command line]],

rendered the .cls file productive.  There's also a `\custombold` command that may be defined elsewhere.  Replacing that with `\bfseries` works.

Yes, `xelatex` is supposed to have capability of finding the system's font files [`/System/Library/Fonts` and `/Library/Fonts`] (mac structure). `xelatex` also may still have a preference of "once and only once defined fonts," as well.

If the Deedy Resume activity was a phase, then this is an academic exercise. Where interest may (still) exist, the specific code can always be added.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I’ll expand on the comments for a real answer.

You shouldn’t use `fontenc` with `fontspec`.  Simply remove the line `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

You don’t clarify why you need to load an 8-bit legacy font in addition to the Unicode font.  Unicode is a strict superset of all legacy encodings and any character in them is also in Unicode.

If, for whatever reason, you do need to use legacy 8-bit font and a modern font in the same document, you would need to install the 8-bit version of the font, look up its NFSS font family, for example `lmr`, and then add the option `NFSSFamily=lmr` to the Fontspec-style font definition.  Another alternative is `substitutefont` to select a replacement font when you tell LaTeX to switch to an encoding that your main font does not come in.  In these cases, you would want to set up the T1 encoding first and then load Unicode (TU) as your default encoding.  Use `\textencoding{T1}` to switch.