# Disable some xunicode macros in case of T1 font encoding?

Tags: macros, xetex, pdftex, luatex, unicode

I was hoping that, except for `inputenc`/`fontenc` versus `fontspec`, old `.tex` files encoded in `UTF-8` could be used without changing anything with either `pdftex`, `xetex` or `luatex` engines.

But the following MWE points out that's not the case because of some
`xunicode`'s public macros, among others `\m`, `\B`, `\G`, `\M`, `\T` and `\U`: too bad that such short, hence popular, macros names were chosen by this package!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdftex_if_engine:TF
{
  \show\m
  \show\B
  \show\G
  \show\M
  \show\T
  \show\U
}
{
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \show\m
  \show\B
  \show\G
  \show\M
  \show\T
  \show\U
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
% \newcommand{\m}{}
% \newcommand{\B}{}
% \newcommand{\G}{}
% \newcommand{\M}{}
% \newcommand{\T}{}
% \newcommand{\U}{}
\end{document}
```

AFAIU, all these macros except `\T` concern `OT1` font encoding and `\T` is defined as `\DeclareRobustCommand{\T}[1]{\~{\m{#1}}}`.

Hence my question: is it possible, in case of `T1` font encoding, to safely patch these macros to disable them (just after `fontspec` load)?

Comment: Note that in the current texlive (and I think miktex) default configuration xelatex does not load hyphenation patterns for T1 encoding.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I should have mentioned that, because of what is mentioned in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115627/18401, I need `T1` font encoding, even in case of `xetex` or `luatex` engines

Comment: OK but you will need to build a custom format or accept bad hyphenation in T1 encoded regions.

Comment: Sigh... Is there another way to use `kpfonts` with `fontspec`?

Comment: the ideal way would be to use font tools to re-encode the font into Unicode encoding just as some other fonts are available in multiple encodings and formats, but that's not really my area....

Comment: kpfonts use URW Palladio, right? So `TeX Gyre Pagella` should be a very close Opentype Replacement for lua- and xelatex. From the Tex Gyre webpage:  `TeX Gyre Pagella is based on the URW Palladio L`

Comment: Note that languages with the alphabet as subset of iso-8859-1 (West Europe latin; French, for example) have no problems when using T1 or Unicoded fonts, because iso-8859-1 is common subset of both mentioned encodings. So, there is no difference between unicoded and T1 encoded French hyphen patterns, you needn't re-encode your favorite T1 encoded font to Unicode, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xunicode sets up for these commands also some OT1 defaults, but the main point are accents commands. E.g.

```
\DeclareEncodedCompositeCharacter{\UTFencname}{\M}{0322}{0322}  % (Combining retroflex hook below)
```

You can naturally redefine the command if you don't use it, but there is a tradition to use "one-char-commands" for accent commands and so I would never use such a name for a command.