# matplotlib pgf backend with lualatex - non-math font does not change

Tags: fonts, luatex, python, matplotlib

When using Python's `matplotlib` to produce plots, I sometimes require the `lualatex` engine using the pgf backend for matplotlib when producing "heavier" plots like hexbin, otherwise the TeX memory is exceeded and `pdflatex` fails. When using `lualatex` The math font seems to change according to my `pgf.preamble`, however, the rest of the font does not, and stays as CM Roman. With `pdflatex`, the font behaves how I want. Note that if I go to [www.overleaf.com](http://www.overleaf.com) and use the same preamble and compile with `pdflatex` or `lualatex`, the document shows the fonts I desire, in both math, and main body. EDIT: the main body font actually does not work in overleaf, I was mistaken.

Update: `xelatex` behaves the same as `lualatex`, ie. only math fonts are changed.

Update: Solved by using `\usepackage{fontspec}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` at the start of the preamble. I thought `fontspec` would not do anything with the T1 font encoding, but it's needed and it works.

This question is similar to: [How do I use kpfonts with fontspec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115627/how-do-i-use-kpfonts-with-fontspec)

With lua engine:
[image]

with pdf engine:
[image]

Code:

```python
import matplotlib as mpl

eng = 'lua' # issue with lua only   <<<<<<<<
# eng = 'pdf' # no issue here
# eng = 'xe' # update: issue here as well

mpl.use('pgf')
mpl.rc('font', family='serif')
mpl.rcParams.update({
        "pgf.rcfonts"  : False,
        "pgf.texsystem": eng + "latex",
        "pgf.preamble" : '\\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}\\usepackage[light]{kpfonts}',
})

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0,6,100)
x = np.sin(t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, x, label='A line')
plt.title('A function, $f(x) = \sin(x)$')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('example.pdf')
```

Comment: Would xetex have the same problem?

Comment: @AlanXiang same issue with xelatex. Btw, I've found your blog to be a great read, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Really glad that you like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set "pgf.preamble" to:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[light]{kpfonts}
```

See: [How do I use kpfonts with fontspec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115627/how-do-i-use-kpfonts-with-fontspec)

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you remove the `preamble` settings and change `example.pdf` to `example.pgf?`. Or is there a reason to use pdf-format?

When I render something in Matplotlib that will be put into Latex, I always choose render with Latex and maybe set some basic settings like (sans-)serif and font size, and choose the output format to be `pgf`.

Doing this and choosing not to set the explicit font, I can later switch fonts without having to render another figure. This is because the actual plot will be plotted when rendering the pdf from Latex (in your case, when you click "Compile" in Overleaf).

If you do this, I think you have to change `\includegraphics{example.pdf}` to `\input{example.pgf}`, since it is LaTeX-code you want to include.

Comment: My reason for using pdf format is compilation speed, portability, archiveability, and the editting and tweaking process is easier for me. I can try to save as .pgf, but my preference is still .pdf

Comment: You can always edit the `pgf` afterwards (even easier than with a `pdf`). You can also choose to plot the same picture and save it in two different formats if you need the `pdf` as well.

Comment: Understood, and good point. I have saved as `pfg` and used `\input` in the past, but I've just found that getting it right in `matplotlib` and saving as a `pdf` and using `includegraphics` has been better for my workflow.