# Beamer with xltxtra: colliding characters in equation

Tags: xetex, kerning, xltxtra

I'm typesetting beamer with XeLaTeX. In equations, variable characters collide with their superscripts.
Also, the parenthesised variable looks somewhat off-set – too far to the right.
It looks good when compiled with `pdflatex` (or just without `xltxtra`, but that's not an option for other reasons).

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xltxtra}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example}
  \begin{block}{Equation~1}
    \[f^\text{cap}(x) = \max(n, f(x))\]
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I assume it's font-related, but since I don't set any fonts manually, it's not something you'd expect to happen.

Comment: If you load the `arev` package to use the Arev font for sans math, the kerning is correct.

Comment: @AlanMunn are you sure `arev` works with XeLaTeX? I installed it, but I get a lot of `Command \nobreakspace unavailable in encoding T1` errors when I put `\usepackage{arev}` in the preamble.

Comment: No errors for me.  TeXLive 2014.  I loaded it after loading `xltxtra`.

Comment: @AlanMunn sure, you're right, the MWE works – I tested `arev` with my actual document. The error can be reproduced, however, by inserting a nobreakspace somewhere (see the minimally updated MWE).

Comment: Okay, I solved it, using this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66949/command-nobreakspace-unavailable-when-switching-to-t1-encoding-under-xelatex/66951#66951

Comment: @AlanMunn Sorry, I'm still confused... `usepackage{arev}` also changes the standard font (outside equations). But with `usepackage{arevmath}` the kerning problem persists... why?

Comment: Looking into this more carefully, I think that `arev` isn't the solution. The real problem is that there are no available OpenType sans serif math fonts.  I think the best solution would be to use a proper OTF math font such as Asana Math for the math.